# Standard exercise in statistics: the case study of battery lifetime

Tags: statistics

I am very frustrated by a standard exercise in statistics. The exercise models the lifetime of a battery via a random variable whose distribution is $$\mathsf{X} \sim \ln\Big( \frac{1}{\theta} \Big)\theta^x  \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}}. $$

I am requested to study it in some detail providing:

> $\mathbb{E}[\mathsf{X}] = - \frac{1}{\ln(\theta)},$
>
> $\text{Var}[\mathsf{X}] = \frac{1}{\ln(\theta)^2},$
>
> Maximum Likelihood Estimator: $\hat{\theta} = \frac{n}{\sum_i X_i}$.
>
> Asymptotic behaviour of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)$: dunno.
>
> Confidence interval: dunno.

Now comes my question, may you **validate my partial answers and help me** with the description of $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)$?

Moreover, I have the feeling that this exercise fits in a cluster of exercises which is probably studied in some book, do you have any **reference**?

Comment: Are you familiar with asymptotic distributions of maximum likelihood estimators? Asymptotic normality?

Comment: Not really. Could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: Maximum likelihood estimators (MLEs) under certain conditions have a limiting distribution which is Normal. See the theorem on page 6 of [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf) lecture note. In particular, this result holds for the MLE in your question.

Comment: Look up the delta method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method

Comment: @StubbornAtom that reference was an answer for me, I would accept it if you upgrade it to an answer.

Comment: Your distribution is just an exponential distribution $f(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ with $\lambda=-\ln\theta$. You can also use the classical Central Limit Theorem alongwith the 'Delta method' as mentioned above to reach the same answer for the limiting distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given distribution to be a valid probability density function (pdf), $\ln\theta$ must be negative, so $\theta$ must lie within $(0,1)$. So we have the pdf of $X$ given by $$f_{\theta}(x)=(-\ln\theta)\theta^x\,\mathbf1_{x>0}\quad,\,\theta\in(0,1)$$

A sample $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ of size $n$ is drawn from this distribution.

Note that the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\theta$ should logically lie within the same parameter space $(0,1)$. Since $\frac{n}{\sum X_i}>0$ almost everywhere, your answer for the MLE cannot be correct. My calculation for the MLE gives $$\hat\theta(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\exp\left(-\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}\right)$$

- As for the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\theta$ (or $\sqrt n(\hat\theta-\theta)$), we can find it without even calculating the MLE. Because general theory says that if some 'regularity conditions' are satisfied by the parent distribution $f_{\theta}$, then asymptotic distribution of the MLE $\hat\theta$ is given by

$$\sqrt n(\hat\theta-\theta)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N\left(0,\frac{1}{I_{X_1}(\theta)}\right)\,,$$

where $I_{X_1}(\theta)=\mathbb E_{\theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(X_1)\right]^2$ is the Fisher information contained in a single observation.

Leaving the calculation of the information function to you.

- From the above limiting distribution, one can obtain a [Wald-type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval) (large sample) confidence interval (CI) for $\theta$. But we can also construct an exact CI.

It can be verified that if $X\sim f_{\theta}$, then $(-2\ln\theta)X\sim \chi^2_2$, a chi-square distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom. So based on the sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, a [pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) for $\theta$ is $(-2\ln\theta)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\sim \chi^2_{2n}$, which can be used to get an exact CI.

---

Asymptotic properties of MLEs are mentioned in [this](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf) set of lecture notes. For more details on these topics, I would suggest looking into standard textbooks on Mathematical Statistics like those of [Casella/Berger](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126) and [Hogg/Craig](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321795431).